# How to make dynamic listdir in Django forms?

Tags: python, django, forms

I need to be able to pick files from server using forms. Now im using os.listdir but its doesn't actualize when new file in folder shows up. List is updating only on server reboot. How can I make updating list of files without server restart? Thanks

Im using Python 2.7 and Django 1.7.

forms.py

```
class OutFileForm(forms.Form):
    file_list = os.listdir(PATH)
    file_list_done = [("", "---")]
    for element in file_list:
        file_list_done.append((element, element))
    outbound_file = forms.ChoiceField(label="Outbound", choices=file_list_done, required=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can prepare it in `__init__` method

```
class OutFileForm(forms.Form):
    outbound_file = forms.ChoiceField(label="Outbound", choices=None, required=True)

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      file_list = os.listdir(PATH)
      file_list_done = [("", "---")]
      for element in file_list:
          file_list_done.append((element, element))
      self.fields['outbound_file'].choices = file_list_done
```